# Deleting transferred purchases from iTunes cache

Tags: itunes, mac

I'm using a long-lived installation of MacOS X alongside with an iPhone and iPad. Because of backups of both devices and the purchased applications, I'm losing a considerable space (~14GB) in my system.

Is it safe to delete the transferred files (from finder, terminal, etc.) or is there a way to do it from iTunes.

Comment: Which "transferred" files are you referring to here? The installed applications, documents you transfer to your iDevice via iTunes or something else?

Comment: The applications that iTunes backs up from your device to save time if ever you ever decide to uninstall an app and re-install later (using iTunes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete Apps from iTunes just go to the Apps section of iTunes.
Select the desired Apps(cmd+click for multiple selection) and cmd+backspace to delete the files.

Your purchases will not be gone, since you can always download them again from the iTunes Store.